# Angular 4 execute requests sequentially, stop if one request fails

Tags: angular, rest, http

I'm sorry to ask like this, but I'm pretty much an Angular noob and stuck with fixing someone else's code, who, I'm afraid, is not that experienced with Angular either.

Here is the code

```
const searchTermStream = this.searchTerm.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .filter(query => query.length > 2 || query.length === 0)
  .do(query => this.adjustBrowserUrl(query))
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(query => this.itemService.findItems(query))
  .subscribe()
;

const paramsStream = this.route.queryParams
  .map(params => decodeURI(params['query'] || ''))
  .do(query => this.searchTerm.setValue(query))
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(query => this.itemService.findItems(query))
  .subscribe()
;

this.itemList$ = this.itemService.items$;

this.itemCount$ = this.itemService.countAllItems();
```

Apparently this code makes rest calls and retrieves items and itemCount from a backend and also filters if query is provided.

The problem is when the first call fails (session timeout) the other calls are still being executed and cause exceptions in the backend, the exceptions are handled properly, but the calls are still unwanted.

So I need to figure out now how to make the calls sequentially and stop the calls altogether if the first one fails (for whatever reasons).
I've found some examples on the net and on here using promises and observables, but since I'm a noob I have a bit trouble making heads or tails of it and adapting those for my purposes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume what you call the first call is this.itemService.items$, can you also add what it returns ?

Comment: it returns items$: Observable<Item[]>; as far as I can tell. There seems to be an awful lot of magic going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this :

```
this.itemList$ = this.itemService.items$;

this.itemList$.subscribe(() => {
   this.itemCount$ = this.itemService.countAllItems();
},
err => {...})
```

don't forget to clean the subscription in your `ngOnDestroy` afterwards ([Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription))

or if you do prefer working with promises :

```
 import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";


 this.itemList$ = this.itemService.items$;

    this.itemList$.toPromise().then(() => {
       this.itemCount$ = this.itemService.countAllItems();
    },
    err => {...})
```

Comment: well, it looks like progress, seems I triggered an infinite loop :D but progress. I guess one distinctUntilChange causes a refresh on the other one and then it goes nuts. But big thanks so far ;)

Comment: I am afraid that without more information here, it's difficult to see why you are having an infinite loop

Comment: hehe yep, I am trying to gather the information atm ;) edit: well, its definitely the distinctUntilChanged

Comment: Does all this mean I have to store the subscription into a class field and then unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy ? ô_o

Comment: That's what it seems, and yeah it is a bit of a hassle

Comment: Doesn't work and I think the premise is wrong, since the request is completed, because the error is handled in an interceptor (taadaa). So I guess I kinda have to handle this in the interceptor, right ?

Comment: hmm thx, well we solved it completely differently now, since nobody could figure it out :D